# Where is the ruby debugger taking me?

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm using the 'debugger' gem to go through some Ruby code. Upon passing line 2 in My Code, the debugger jumps into a frame after frame of scurrilous Ruby functions and methods.  What's happening here. I've stepped about 50 times through the debugger and it hasn't jumped back to my code yet.

**My Code**

```
[-3, 6] in C:/RUBY/prep-work-master/coding-test-2/practice-problems/spec/00_neare
   1  require '00_nearest_larger'
=> 2  require 'rspec'
   3
   4  # Write a function, `nearest_larger(arr, i)` which takes an array and an
   5  # index.  The function should return another index, `j`: this should
   6  # satisfy:
(rdb:1) n
```

**Debugger jumps here: Where is this?**
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:982
    spec = @path_to_default_spec_map["#{path}#{suffix}"]

```
[977, 986] in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   977      ##
   978      # Find a Gem::Specification of default gem from +path+
   979
   980      def find_unresolved_default_spec(path)
   981        Gem.suffixes.each do |suffix|
=> 982          spec = @path_to_default_spec_map["#{path}#{suffix}"]
   983          return spec if spec
   984        end
   985        nil
   986      end
(rdb:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking you inside the implementation of `require`.

Comment: Do you know how to get skip that and get back to my original function again?

Comment: There's a rdb command prompt and I invoke the debugger with commands like 'continue', 'next' and 'step' to move through my code. Mostly its ok unless it jumps out to some ruby libraries.  Then I toggle through 30 frames until it jumps back to my original code.

Comment: No, I know what it looks like when you get to the rdb prompt.  How are you getting there?  What command do you run from the Windows prompt?

Comment: ok.  require "debugger" at the top of my file. put the line 'debugger' where i want the debugger to begin. then i rake the file from dos, and it brings me inside the debugger

Answer (score 1):

The `debugger` gem doesn't work properly for Ruby >= 2.0. Its main problem is `next` command "stepping into" instead of going to the next line.

Try [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) instead. *Disclaimer:* I'm `byebug`'s author.